# Why does Google App Script getRange think I'm giving it a class instead of a number?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that copies some data from one sheet and puts it in another sheet. For some reason the line `toAppend[i] = projectSheet.getRange(rowsToCheck[i], projectColumn).getValue();` causes an error: "Cannot find method getRange((class),number)." Why is this happening? If rowsToCheck is an array of numbers, shouldn't rowsToCheck[i] be a number, not a class? I'm especially confused because I haven't created any classes in my code. How can I get getRange() to treat rowsToCheck[i] as a number? Relevant code is below.
EDIT: I even did `console.log(typeof rowsToCheck[0])` and it returned "number" so what gives?

```
var textFinder = projectSheet.createTextFinder("Cumulative Actuals");
var rowSearch = textFinder.findNext().getRow();
//making an array of rows to check (skipping over some data that I don't want to copy over)
for(var i = 0; i<=8; i++){
    if(projectSheet.getRange(rowSearch, projectColumn).isBlank()){
      for(var j = 0; j<4; j++){
        rowSearch++; 
      }
    }
    else{
      rowsToCheck.push(rowSearch);
      rowSearch++;
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<=rowsToCheck.length; i++){
    toAppend[i] = projectSheet.getRange(rowsToCheck[i], projectColumn).getValue();
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked _all_ of the types of `rowsToCheck`, not just the first element? You could try using `parseInt(rowsToCheck[i],10)`, but that wouldn't explain why you're experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue might be `for(i=0; i<=rowsToCheck.length; i++){`. When `i` becomes to `rowsToCheck.length`, `rowsToCheck[i]` returns `undefined`. When `rowsToCheck[i]` is `undefined`, such error occurs. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for(i=0; i<=rowsToCheck.length; i++){
```

#### To:

```
for(i=0; i<rowsToCheck.length; i++){
```

Comment: This was the problem, thanks! I still don't know why it thought it was a class though? I feel I would have been able to solve this much sooner if the error said "Cannot find method getRange(undefined ,number)".

Comment: @arcadianrhythm Thank you for replying. Yes. I think so. About `(class)`, I think that such error message is due to Google side. Although I can understand the reason that the error occurs, I cannot know about the clear reason  that `(class)` is shown. I apologize for this.